# Java rename and sort based upon the filename

Tags: java

Is there an easy way to create a method that enables you to take the date of a file's creation and append it to the front of the file name?  Example is a file named blah1.doc that was created on December 4, 2010 be rename to 2010124blah.doc.

If that is possible, is there a way to sort the files based upon creation date and copy them to different folders based upon filename?

Comment: Please let us know what you tried. Then we can help with what didn't work.

Comment: @Adel nothing i guess :)

Comment: Not all file systems record the creation date.  What about the last modification date?

Comment: This would be possible yes

Comment: `copy them to different folders based upon filename?` Assuming you don't have a magic requirement for splitting between folders then yes

Answer (score 2):

Since some Linux systems do not support creation timestamps, this is not always doable.

Use [Java nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) if you are working on a system that does provide timestamps.

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

// create new file object
newFile = new File(attr.creationTime() + ".doc");

// rename file
oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
```